# C# WebApi DI not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Hello i need some assistance. I'm struggling on this second day and can't find a source of the problem. I'm working on web api with token authorization , identity and ninject.

This is my kernel :

```
 public IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<AppContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind(x => { x.From(typeof(UserService).Assembly).SelectAllClasses().EndingWith("Service").BindDefaultInterface(); });

        kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserStore<AppIdentityUser>)).To(typeof(UserStore<AppIdentityUser>)).InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<AppContext>());


        kernel.Bind(typeof(UserManager<AppIdentityUser>)).To(typeof(UserManager<AppIdentityUser>)).InRequestScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("store", kernel.Get<IUserStore<AppIdentityUser>>());

        kernel.Bind(typeof(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>)).To(typeof(RoleStore<IdentityRole>)).InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<AppContext>());
        kernel.Bind(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole>)).To(typeof(RoleManager<IdentityRole>)).InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("store", kernel.Get<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>());

        kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().To<AuthorizationServerProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>().To<MyOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>();


        return kernel;
    }
```

This is my api controller :

```
         public UsersController(IUserService userService)
            {
                this._userService = userService;
            }
     public IHttpActionResult Login()
            {
//get user method 
    }
```

this is my service :

```
     public UserService(UserManager<AppIdentityUser> userMenager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            this._userMenager = userMenager;
            this._roleManager = roleManager;
        }

   public AppIdentityUser GetUser(string name, string password)
        {
            return _userMenager.Find(name, password);  // here I recive error on second time
        }
```

Problem is that this works only once. When i open application and perform one get action it works on the second time when i try after few seconds i get exception that Context in user Store is disposed. I suspect that it's problem with my ninject configuration but don't see any error.

**Edit: this is my Owin Startup Class**

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableCors();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        var kernel = ConfigureNinject(app);

        ConfigureOAuth(app, kernel);
        config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);

        //app.UseWebApi(config);
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => kernel);
        app.UseNinjectWebApi(config);

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, IKernel kernel)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(kernel.Get<IOAuthAuthorizationServerOptions>().GetOptions());
    }
```

Comment: I would just like to say, I would honestly wrap your `RoleManager` in a `RoleManagerFactory` it will make DI so much easier... I do it for all my projects and  I tend to go one step further and but an adapter round them, so not to leak EF into my apps. (but that is preferential)

Comment: Could you share a example? Now in my app i recive random context dispose in identity stores (on another services dbcontext is injected as it should only identity stores are problematic) i'm complitly don't know what to do.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I can provide you with some code for sure, give me 20mins

Comment: Long 20 mins...